# How to save terminal snapshot using ordinary repositories

Tags: javers

I'm using ordinary repositories and save/delete repository methods annotated with `@JaversAuditable`.

Only **INITIAL** and **UPDATE** snapshots were persisted.

What is the best way to enable `commitShallowDelete` to save TERMINAL snapshots without Spring Data?

Create another aspect class that calls commit and commitShallowDelete?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, look like a missing feature in JaVers. So you need to write your own aspect or contribute a PR to JaVers with support for the new annotation, let's say `@JaversAuditableDelete`.